# How to increase size of select button in <select> field?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the size of the downward-pointing arrow button in a `<select>` field.
My code is something similar to below:

```
<select>
  <option>Select City</option>
  <option>City1</option>
  <option>City2</option>
</select>
```

How can I make the arrow button bigger?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: @CDnDT You want to increase size of `select-button-arrow` or full `select box`

Answer (score 4):

I got it done using fake div. 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/dGTg3/)

```
.styleSelect {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 168px;
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css code

```
select
{
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: i guess he want to increase size of `select-button-arrow` and not full `select box`

Comment: it is up to him to be more specific

Comment: Yes I want to increase size of select-button-arrow. Is it possible to do it or I have to create a button using div.

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` element is generated by the application and styling is not part of the `CSS/HTML` spec.

You would have to fake it with your own `DIV` and overlay it on top of the existing one, or build your own control emulating the same functionality.

Comment: Consider deleting this answer, given you've written a better one.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Even though i got the answer but it is based on this thesis. :)